# Kibana bootstrapping with Yarn - Errors 800A0404/800A1391

Tags: javascript, node.js, kibana, jscript, yarnpkg

**UPDATE 2**: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on my other computer either. While elasticsearch boots just fine, kibana.bat gives an "Unable to find usable node.js executable" message on boot. Though I know it's dangerous, I think I am just going to try to develop on the production version of Kibana from the Elastic website. Should I submit a bug request about this?

**UPDATE 1**: I went into the kibana\packages\kbn-babel-preset\node.js file & got rid of some of the commas at the end of lists/dictionary objects, which fixed the 800A0404 error, but caused another:

```
Script: C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-babel-preset\node.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: 'module' is undefined
Code: 800A1391
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

Dismissing this popup allows the bootstrap to continue until hitting the eslint-import-resolver-kibana directory:

```
Installing dependencies in [@kbn/eslint-import-resolver-kibana]:

[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check.
Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.8.4" has unmet peer dependency "esl
int-plugin-import@>=1.4.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⠈ uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
[-/1] ⠈ waiting...
[-/1] ⠈ waiting...
[-/1] ⠈ waiting...
error C:\Users\super\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-eslint-import-resolver-kibana
\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/post_install.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\super\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-eslint-import-resolver-k
ibana\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
Output:
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\super\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-eslint-i
mport-resolver-kibana\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\lib\post_install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)

[bootstrap] failed:

Error: Command failed: yarn install --non-interactive --mutex file
    at makeError (C:\Users\super\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-pm\dist\index.js:
38964:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Users\super\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-pm\dis
t\index.js:39069:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Once again: any advice is greatly appreciated!

**ORIGINAL**: I am new to Kibana plugin & JavaScript development & would appreciate some help with an error I have been attempting to troubleshoot for a little while now.

I am attempting to set up my developer environment for creating Kibana plugins as per [this guide](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-your-development-environment). However, I only just recently started getting the following popup error from the Windows Script Host on running the `yarn kbn bootstrap` command in the cloned kibana directory, shortly after cloning the Kibana Github directory and installing Yarn & Node.js:

```
Script: C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-babel-preset\node.js
Line: 13
Char: 9
Error: Expected identifier, string or number
Code: 800A0404
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

After clicking OK to dismiss this popup, here is what appears in the shell:

```
super@DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/kibana (master)
$ yarn kbn bootstrap
yarn run v1.6.0
$ node scripts/kbn bootstrap
Running [bootstrap] command from [C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Documents\kibana]:

Found [16] projects:

kibana
├── packages
│   ├── eslint-config-kibana (@elastic/eslint-config-kibana)
│   ├── eslint-plugin-kibana-custom (@elastic/eslint-plugin-kibana-custom)
│   ├── kbn-babel-preset (@kbn/babel-preset)
│   ├── kbn-datemath (@kbn/datemath)
│   ├── kbn-dev-utils (@kbn/dev-utils)
│   ├── kbn-es (@kbn/es)
│   ├── kbn-eslint-import-resolver-kibana (@kbn/eslint-import-resolver-kibana)
│   ├── kbn-eslint-plugin-license-header (@kbn/eslint-plugin-license-header)
│   ├── kbn-plugin-generator (@kbn/plugin-generator)
│   ├── kbn-plugin-helpers (@kbn/plugin-helpers)
│   ├── kbn-pm (@kbn/pm)
│   ├── kbn-system-loader (@kbn/system-loader)
│   ├── kbn-test-subj-selector (@kbn/test-subj-selector)
│   └── kbn-ui-framework (@kbn/ui-framework)
└── x-pack

Running installs in topological order:


Installing dependencies in [@kbn/babel-preset]:


[bootstrap] failed:

Error: Command failed: yarn install --non-interactive --mutex file
    at makeError (C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Documents\kibana\packages\kbn-pm\dist\
index.js:38964:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\Users\super\OneDrive\Documents\kibana\packages\k
bn-pm\dist\index.js:39069:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The above error only occurs when I go to run yarn kbn bootstrap in the Git Bash terminal. Immediately after, I uninstalled/reinstalled Java v.8, v.10, Node.js, and Yarn with computer restarts in between, figuring that since the script host mentions JScript compilation that un-/reinstalling Java would help, but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What were you doing before and after the error started showing up? Can you create a [mcve] that re-creates the problem?

Comment: @Blacksilver Thank you for your response! I am installing dependencies for Kibana per the guide above, & I am at the point of running `yarn kbn bootstrap`. Before the error occurred, I cloned kibana from github in my Documents directory, installed node.js v.8.11.0, and installed Yarn. The above error only occurs when I go to run `yarn kbn bootstrap` in the Git Bash terminal. Immediately after, I uninstalled/reinstalled Java v.8, v.10, Node.js, and Yarn with computer restarts in between. I am going to crosspost to Kibana's official forum as well & see if this is a known error.

Comment: Try running `yarn kbn clean` and then try `yarn kbn bootstrap` again

Comment: @Elizabeth Please [edit] your question to incorporate that information.

Comment: @NathanReese Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I ran into the same error after cleaning.

Comment: @Blacksilver Thank you -- done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors seemed to have been caused by the Windows Script Host opening the .js files instead of Node.js.

Instead of installing Yarn manually from the official website, I installed it with `node install -g yarn` [at the suggestion of a Kibana dev](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/18701), and these errors finally cleared up... except for the one in the /eslint-import-resolver-kibana directory but that's not the topic of this thread. :')

Thanks again to everyone who provided support!